# Why is django allauth redirecting to /accounts/login/?=next/MY_PAGE instead of logging in?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am attempting to handle user authentication on a site using Django allauth. However, upon entering a username and password and clicking "log in" on my site, I am redirected to /accounts/login/?=next/MY_PAGE and the login page is simply reloaded. I have seen a number of similar questions, and I know that sometimes people run into issues with this when authenticating with socials, but I am not using any form of social authentication. I already have the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL set to the desired page's URL, and I attempted to create an adapter as follows:

```
class AccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def is_open_for_signup(self, request):
        return getattr(settings, "ACCOUNT_ALLOW_REGISTRATION", True)

    def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
        path = "/news/"
        return path
```

where get_login_redirect_url should direct the application to the desired page. I have read in other posts that the fact that the next page (in this case "News") isn't being loaded means that allauth is not actually logging me in, and that's why I end up just getting the login page reloaded. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction? Thanks!

ADDITIONAL INFO
Here is how I am attempting to handle the login now.

```
<!-- <form class="login" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_login' %}"> -->
            <form class="login" method="POST" action="{% if request.path|slice:':6' == '/login' %}/news{% else %}{{request.path}}{% endif %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
            {% if redirect_field_value %}
              <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
            {% endif %}
            <div class="form-group container-login100-form-btn">
              <button type="submit" class="login100-form-btn">{% trans 'Log In' %}</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group container-login100-form-btn">
              <a href="{% url 'account_signup' %}" class="btn btn-link">{% trans 'Or sign up for ConnectHer here' %}</a>
              <a href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}" class="btn btn-link pull-right">{% trans 'Forgot your password?' %}</a>
            </div>
          </form>
```

The commented out line at the top was my orig version of the form before attempting to fix my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you showing the `login` link to the user?  I'd bet that the link on your login page is something like:

```
<a href="/login?next={{ request.path }}">Login</a>
```

which is basically (when on the login page):

```
<a href="/login?next=/login">Login</a>
```

which send you right back.  You can test in the template to set the `next=` param:

```
<form class="login" method="POST" action="/login?next={% if request.path|slice:':6' == '/login' %}/news{% else %}{{request.path}}{% endif %}">
```

Bonus:

Here is how to add a `|startswith` filter to your template:

```
def startswith(val1, val2):
    if not val1:
        return False
    else:
        return val1.startswith(val2)

register.filter("startswith", startswith)
```

Comment: Thanks! In my case, it's not a direct link, but a form. Therefore, I tried implementing what you said in the action for my form, but I'm still having the exact same problem unfortunately. I had to use the slice filter instead of startswith because I was getting a template error about startswith being invalid. I edited my question to show my form code to give some more context. I appreciate the help!

Comment: You forgot the `/login?next=` part of the `action`. See edit.  Sorry, I forgot I add a `startswith` filter to apps.

Comment: No worries, and thanks. I had actually tried that before, but when I do that, I get redirected to /login?next=/accounts/login/ rather than just /news. (So, for me, that's just a "page not found" error now.)

Comment: That would be because you are testing for `request.path|slice:':6' == '/login'`, when your path tests as `request.path|slice:':6' = '/accou'`.  Test for `|slice:15 == '/accounts/login'`

Comment: Oh, my bad. Thanks for pointing that out. I tried the whole line exactly like this: <form class="login" method="POST" action="{% if request.path|slice:15 == '/accounts/login' %}/news{% else %}{{request.path}}{% endif %}"> But, unfortunately that just led me back to square one, redirecting me to: /accounts/login/?next=/news/ rather than /news (Also, thanks for the bonus info!)

Comment: No.  Check my answer again.  You forogt the `action="/login?next={% if ...` again

Comment: Ok, added the action="/login?next={% if back in. Now it's redirecting to /login?next=/news which is kind of closer to what I need, but still getting stuck there.

Comment: So, accept this answer and ask a new question about where you are now stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put this on your settings file:

```
LOGIN_URL = "/login/"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/xxx/"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Found default: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#login-url